# using Webdav .Net Engine from ITHits for direct edit MS Office File

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I'm trial http://www.webdavsystem.com/ .Net WebDav Server and having problem direct editing on Word file which always open in read-only mode. (tested with Visio, Excel same problem)

I've tried several things noted in the page http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/prev/v2/documentation/ms_office_read_only

Here are the results

- Yes: My WebDAV configured on server site root.
- Yes: My WebDAV support Class 2. (using built-in wizard to generate project)
- No: I didn't open web-hyperlinked file, I opened from M:\Folder\File.doc as Mapped Drive
- Yes: I've Cleared Microsoft Office WebDAV cache in registry.
- Yes: I've Excluded client side MS Office issues. By testing with
  www.ajaxfilebrowser.com, works perfectly.

Two things I can't really do by suggestions on the webpage are

1. I've enable Log flag in Web.config file and attached here
   http://www.sendspace.com/file/fp3yrz as I can't really understand
   Log syntax much.
2. Also I don't know much enough to try with Fiddle (Examine WebDAV
   requests with a Fiddler tool ) And my server configured to use
   Digest Authentication over Standard HTTP, it seemed to work - drive
   mapping has no a problem.

My Environment : VS2012 Ultimate ran on Win7 ultimate 6GB Ram (also act as a client pc), Server : Winserver 2012 Std, 2GBRam

Comment: They encourage asking on SO, I think their idea is to keep on this site so that it might help others too.

Comment: Eric, could you please clarify what is your Microsoft Office version?

Answer (score 1):

I examined your log, it looks ok, I did not found any issues.

Microsoft Mini-redirector many cache authentication info. Here is what else you can try:

1. Unmount your WebDAV folders using net use * /DELETE command (or its variants).
2. Clear saved logins using following command:

   rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr

Answer (score 1):

LOCK request should reach success for an Office document to be opened for editing (not read-only). This will ensure that the document will not be edited by two or more persons at a time.
But in your log file I can see 5 LOCK request and 4 of them failed (with reductions):

```
[7] [LOCK] /685/test_D47H.doc
User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601
Timeout: Second-3600

[7] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:lockinfo xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope><D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype><D:owner><D:href>admin</D:href></D:owner></D:lockinfo>

[7] HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.17929 32bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.1.869.0 (Evaluation License)

[7] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:">
 <d:need-privileges>
  <d:responsedescription>Not enough privileges</d:responsedescription>
   <d:resource>
    <d:href>http://webdrive.test.com/685/test_D47H.doc</d:href>
    <d:privilege>
     <d:write />
    </d:privilege>
   </d:resource>
  </d:need-privileges>
</d:error>
```

"Not enough privileges" - this means an UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown when trying to create an alternate stream for the file /685/test_D47H.doc. And LOCK request is the only attempt to change this file (all other requests just read its properties).

But later you are creating file /685/test_D47H%20-%20Copy.doc and all the changing requests succeed (like PUT, PROPPATCH, UNLOCK).

This means the file /685/test_D47H.doc is write protected and any new created file - is not.